# Is answering "Is it Dangerous" (even in the negative) Medical Advice?

Tags: discussion

Looking at question [Are ground bottle gourd and snake gourd seeds edible?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/88880/6279) OP concludes his question *"Is this dangerous to eat?"*

I'm reasonably sure the answer is "No"...but does that violate our standards for "medical advice"?

Answer (score 3):

We often make a distinction between health/medical/nutrition advice and food safety. I believe the same concept applies here, making "is it edible or is it dangerous?" an acceptable question, even if it could perhaps be rephrased.

The distinction is roughly that food safety is about the immediate future, while health/medical/nutrition advice is about things that might on average happen to people over a long period of time. The former is relatively straightforward, while the latter is quite difficult to answer (and has very little to do with cooking). Eating food that's been left out too long is pretty risky in clear ways in the short term; eating too much saturated fat, who knows.

Edible vs dangerous is similar to food safety: either you can eat it or you can't. If the question were whether it's *healthy*, yeah, that'd stray off-topic, but I think edible vs dangerous is fine, though perhaps edible vs inedible is clearer.