# Why was my lettuce - e.coli question deleted?

Tags: discussion

My lettuce - e.coli question got deleted but isn't food safety on-topic here?

For example, this Meta discussion would indicate that my question was on-topic, answered by cascabel:

[Is answering "Is it Dangerous" (even in the negative) Medical Advice?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/is-answering-is-it-dangerous-even-in-the-negative-medical-advice)

... in particular, with regards to "food safety in the immediate future".

Comment: "Immediate future" in the answer you quoted is *not* referring to current events or the food you're about to eat right this moment. It's referring to the immediate future after a person eats food, i.e. foodborne illness that makes people sick within a day or two (as opposed to health/nutrition things that take months or years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't delete it so I'm going to defer on the "why?"

[Your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89302/how-do-i-know-if-lettuce-is-safe-given-the-e-coli-outbreak) is, to the best of my knowledge, borderline on topic and is now reopened. Food safety is in general on topic, and it seems like the unusual thing about your core question is that it's current events instead of advice that will always apply. You *did* ask about ordering restaurant food instead of cooking, but the answer is the same for both so it's probably not worth us worrying too much about.

It did need some editing to meet quality standards, which I've done and explained there.